# Dynamic tables from fluent nHibernate

Tags: c#, jquery, linq, linq-to-nhibernate

I am in the prototype phaze of a large system we are developing. We are using NHibernate and Fluent on top of that. We have a huge number of classes in the Core project.

In the main web application we have to list up countries, currencies and such, and I have been looking into some ways of doing that.

I like the [DataTables plugin](http://www.datatables.net/) for jQuery, and would really like to use that.

And to make things as dynamic as possible, I would like to select a list of Country and Currency classes in one usercontrol.

But I am having problems with this ... does anyone here have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a case for a DTO, and a named query from an NHibernate perspective.

Read more about it here: http://gustavoringel.blogspot.com/2009/02/creating-dto-in-nhibernate-hql-using.html.